# passing variables outside of functions php

Tags: php, function

I have a function that checks form validation. If there is an error then there is a variable called $error. How do I make it so outside of this function and the rest of this page regardless of inside of a function or not, know that $error is set?

I don't want it to carry over to another page though. I know there is global but since I am initiating the $error in a function I guess it is not available in other functions.

Any ideas?

Comment: You want a globally accessible variable which is not global?

Comment: You might look for a form library that deals with such in a consistent and accessible manner.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set and use a global variable via the [superglobal `$GLOBALS` array <sup>**PHP Manual**</sup>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php):

```
$GLOBALS['error'] = value;
```

That array is available everywhere. So take care.

Comment: so if value is $error, which is a string, then now $_GLOBALS['error'] is now available anywhere even though it was created in a function? Once I set $_GLOBALS['error'] in my function it sees it is set but when I call the same thing in another function it doesn't know it is set. And of course I call the later function after the initial function that set it.

Comment: It's a global. it's visible everywhere (through the superglobal). why don't you try it?

Comment: typical SO. answered the question and got downvoted. Yes, it's not a good practice to use globals, but the question was how can he access the validation results *everywhere* in the code.

Comment: @yi_H: The OP is really specifically asking for this. Like a static class member is a global, that's as well.

Comment: @yi_H: edited your question, you've used the wrong variable name and a little link is always helpful.

Comment: I wasn't the one who down voted but simply answering the question and promoting bad practice is not ideal. Although I can understand your thoughts on just answering the questions I was going to attempt to but I would have gone for an OO encapsulation like @iLLin but seems as no code was given it's hard to gauge the whether the OP is using OO and if so to what level. So if you want to avoid down vote I find it's prob best to enquire for more info about the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I would make it this way
`function validate($form, &$errors)

{

   // some code that sets the erros variable

   return false;

}`

Since $erros is passed by reference, the function can set it's value. But the variable itself remains in the scope of the calling code.

Answer (score 1):

I have a form class with a static variable inside of it that logs errors.  For example:

```
<?php
class form {
  //this is our array to hold fields that have errored so we can apply an error class to the input fields
  static public $errors = array();
  static public function setError($error) {
    self::$errors[] = $error;
  }
  static public function parseErrors() {
    $output .= '<ul>';
    foreach(self::$errors as $message) {
      $output .= '<li>'.$message.'</li>';
    }
    $output .= '</ul>';
    return $output;
  }
  //... other functions
}
?>
```

Then to log errors from within your validation functions, you can do something like this:

```
<?php
function myvalidate($value) {
  // if this validation fails
  form::setError('Field is required');
}
?>
```

Then just call the parseErrors to spit out your errors.  Please note these are just snippets.  I actually have a logger class that interacts with the form class, changed it up some for consolidation.

I prefer doing things like this than using GLOBALS, it can get messy really quick using GLOBALS or the SESSION for that matter, which is another option.

Comment: Also, you can pass the field_name through all of this and beef this up more so you can target input fields to add "error" classes to the field when validation fails.

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather return it, and checks its count() (I usually put errors in array). If it's > 0 then there are errors, otherwise there are no.

Comment: so if you return it you are making that variable available to whatever page called the original function in the first place right? The problem is the function that checks for validation then sees if there are any errors and if so it sends those errors to another function to properly display the error messages. So if I were to return it in the last function would it return it to the other function or to the main page?

Comment: I'm a bit unclear about your question (too many it) @.@. However, it's something like (inside validate caller, pseudo code): errors = validate(...); if count(errors) > 0 then displayerrors(errors);